# Why is using Firebase Functions as an API endpoint so slow?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, slack

I built an app in Slack, that on interactions in Slack, [will send an HTTP POST request to a URL](https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity#understanding_payloads). That URL is a Firebase Function that is [triggered with an HTTP request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#trigger_a_function_with_an_http_request).

The Firebase Function looks like this...

```
// process incoming shortcuts
exports.interactions = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  response.send();
  const payload = JSON.parse(request.body.payload);
  functions.logger.log(payload);

  if (payload.type === 'shortcut') {
    functions.logger.log('Found a shortcut...');
    const shortcuts = require('./shortcuts');
    await shortcuts(payload);
  } else if (payload.type === 'block_actions') {
    functions.logger.log('Found a block action...');
    const blockActions = require('./blockActions');
    await blockActions(payload);
  } else if (payload.type === 'view_submission') {
    functions.logger.log('Found a view submission...');
    const viewSubmissions = require('./viewSubmissions');
    await viewSubmissions(payload);
  }
  functions.logger.log('Done with interactions.');
});
```

The problem is, is that Firebase is taking 5-10 seconds to respond, and [Slack is expecting a response in 3 seconds](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#acknowledgment_response).

So the app in Slack erroring out.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out while I thought it would be useful to do a `response.send()` immediately when the function was called so that Slack had its instant response, I was then also inadvertently starting [background activities in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#do_not_start_background_activities).

The line in the above Firebase docs that gave me the biggest clue was:

> Background activity can often be detected in logs from individual invocations, by finding anything that is logged after the line saying that the invocation finished.

Which I found here... the function started, and completed, and then the code to open a modal began to be executed...

[image]

I then found [in the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)

> Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().

So all I really had to do was move `response.send()` to the end of the function. Also I had to make sure that I had `await` statements before my async functions, so that async functions waited to be resolved before executing the final `response.send()`

```
// process incoming shortcuts
exports.interactions = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const payload = JSON.parse(request.body.payload);
  functions.logger.log(payload);

  if (payload.type === 'shortcut') {
    functions.logger.log('Found a shortcut...');
    const shortcuts = require('./shortcuts');
    await shortcuts(payload);
  } else if (payload.type === 'block_actions') {
    functions.logger.log('Found a block action...');
    const blockActions = require('./blockActions');
    await blockActions(payload);
  } else if (payload.type === 'view_submission') {
    functions.logger.log('Found a view submission...');
    const viewSubmissions = require('./viewSubmissions');
    await viewSubmissions(payload);
  }
  functions.logger.log('Done with interactions.');
  response.send();
});
```

The modal interaction response times in Slack are much quicker and usable now.